# Where do i get the vendor stripe account url page after they are successfully onboard?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

How do i get the vendor stripe account url page after they are successfully onboard? where do I get them?

we are a marketplace with many vendor. i wanted to create a button on the vendor(connected account) page and when they click on the button on our dashboard. it goes to the vendor stripe page but I just cant get the connect account URL for the vendor.

```
return stripe.accountLinks.create({
  type: "account_onboarding",
  account: accountID,
  refresh_url: `${origin}/`,
  return_url: `${origin}/`,
});
```

examples link: https://connect.stripe.com/express/m7ucEu2cZPbD

[image: baord]

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by the "vendor stripe account url page"?  Do you mean the https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-dashboard?

Comment: the page that i am showing example link: https://connect.stripe.com/express/m7ucEu2cZPbD

Comment: how do i get the example link

Comment: there is no way i can link my vendor to their stripe account page on my dashboard.

Comment: You can, but you need to have the button on your dashboard send the user to a server-side route that can create the Account Link, and then redirect them to that link, as described in the doc I linked.